# Copying array columns

Tags: julia

I have an algorithm that requires one column of an array to be replaced by another column of the same array.
I tried doing it with slices, and element-wise.

```
const M = 10^4
const N = 10^4
A = rand(Float32, M, N)
B = rand(Float32, N, M)

function copy_col!(A::Array{Float32,2},col1::Int,col2::Int)
  A[1:end,col2] = A[1:end,col1]
end

function copy_col2!(A::Array{Float32,2},col1::Int,col2::Int)
  for i in 1:size(A,1)
    A[i,col2] = A[i,col1]
  end
end

[Both functions+rand are called here once for compilation]

@time (for i in 1:20000 copy_col!(B, rand(1:size(B,2)),rand(1:size(B,2)) ); end )
@time (for i in 1:20000 copy_col2!(B, rand(1:size(B,2)),rand(1:size(B,2)) ); end )

>>  0.607899 seconds (314.81 k allocations: 769.879 MB, 25.05% gc time)
>>  0.213387 seconds (117.96 k allocations: 2.410 MB)
```

Why does copying using slices perform so much worse? Is there a better way than what `copy_col2!` does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A[1:end,col1]` makes a copy of indexed column first then it copies over to `A[1:end,col2]` so `copy_col!` allocates more and runs longer. There are `sub`, `slice`, and `view` that may remedy allocations in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I should read the docs more thoroughly. Indeed, using `sub` has about the same runtime as element-wise copy. Still needs more allocations, but that's fine. Looks cleaner, too. You wouldn't have any idea how to optimize further?

Comment: I think it is normal that using `sub` and others allocate some because they wraps a column of `A` around a new object. If element-wise copy is used you can further optimize with `@inbounds`(maybe in conjunction with @simd) like
`
@simd @inbounds for i in 1:size(A,1)
    A[i,col2] = A[i,col1]
  end
`
I am not sure how to reflect that to the method with `sub`. Also, did you do `A[:,col1]=sub(A,:,col2)`? or something else?

Comment: I did precisely that. I will try with inbounds and simd too and post the results. But after Easter.